# Multiple Conditions in an If statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multiple-conditions

```
if (gold >= 5 || (item1 = false) ) { 
  item1 = true;
  gold = gold - 5;
}
```

This will keep going even if item1 is true. I'd like for the function to not run if either of those are not met. Thank you

Comment: `item1 == false` or `!item1`

Comment: _"I'd like for the function to not run if either of those are not met."_ - Could you rephrase that please? Do you mean the assignments should happen if either condition is true, or only if _both_ are true (in which case you need `&&` not `||`)?

Answer (score 5):

Item1 = false is an assignment which will always evaluate as false.

You need item1 == false

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the difference between assignment (`=`) and equivalence comparison (`==`). Your code is assigning the value of false to the variable item1. To evaluate the value of item1, use:

```
if (gold >= 5 || item1 == false ) {
    item1 = true;
    gold = gold - 5;
}
```

Also, the additional nesting within parentheses is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
if (gold >= 5 || (item1 = false) ) { item1 = true; gold = gold - 5; }
```

With this:

```
if (gold >= 5 || (item1 == false) ) { item1 = true; gold = gold - 5; }
```

With 2 = signs you check the equivalence. With 1 = sign you are assigning the variabile, noto comparing it. Hope this helps